# How to download LibreOffice from the main server?

Tags: libreoffice

I want to install the latest version of LibreOffic , but when I go to the website it shows "Download from torrent", but I don't want to use a torrent.

How can I download LibreOffice from the main server?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what’s the problem with BitTorrent? It’s usually fast and effective, unless your network blocks it.

Comment: The [Libreoffice website](http://www.libreoffice.org) is both easy to navigate and has simple, obvious ways to download both deb and snap versions. We are not the maintainers of the Libreoffice website. You really should ask *them*,..or use Ubuntu's Software Center, which we do provide support for.

Comment: I have fear to use bit torrent   because I listen something from my some friend that . It's illegal to use torrent.  So I don't use torrent . May be all my thinking are wrong and I have misunderstanding ..... All tho thanks you all to guide me,.....

Comment: BitTorrent is just a way to download large files. There's nothing illegal about it. (Now, *because* it's an efficient way to transfer large files, people tend to use it for sharing films and suchlike, infringing copyright, but there's nothing illegal with the BitTorrent protocol itself.)

Comment: Ohh now I get it. But I don't know why  I feel some uncomfortable to use torrent . So mostly don't preferre torrent .  And use the main server . And thank for your information . Now I will get it .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need the latest version (6.1.4) for Ubuntu (.deb) in English, [This link](https://download.documentfoundation.org/libreoffice/stable/6.1.4/deb/x86/LibreOffice_6.1.4_Linux_x86_deb.tar.gz.mirrorlist) is what I get by going to their download page and selecting "manually select a mirror". At the bottom of the list is also a direct download link.

Comment: Yes I downloaded Linux_x86-64_deb . Thank you so much for your guidance